# error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘}’ token

Tags: c, compilation

I am making a small life and poison counter for a game called MTG(Magic the Gathering), and I cam across some problems that wont let me compile can anyone help? Sorry if they're simple, I'm new to C...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int life = 20;
int poison = 0;
int amount;
char pn;
char lp;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

while(1){
system("clear");
printf("Life:%d\nPoison Counters:%d\n\n\n", life, poison);
printf("\n\n<Life or Poison>(l/p) <positive or negative>(+/-) <amount>(#)\n\n\n>>>");
scanf("\n\n%c %c %d", &lp, &pn, &amount);
if(lp == 'l'){
    if(pn == '+'){
    life = life + amount;
    }
    else{
    life = life - amount;
    }
}else if(lp == 'p'){
    if(pn == '+'){
    poison = poison + amount;
    }
    else{
    poison = poison - amount;
    }
}else if(lp == 'q'){
break;
}
}
}
    }
return 0;
}
```

This is what Terminal is telling me...

```
mtglife.c:36:2: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘}’ token
mtglife.c:37:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘return’
mtglife.c:38:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘}’ token
```

Comment: Did the error message have a line number?

Comment: Indent your code properly (your editor may have the functionality to do so built in) and you will see you've mismatched your braces.

Comment: I think my braces were ok gcc doesnt care to much about tabs also

Comment: When you run into such issues frequently, I would recommend to reconsider your way to indent code and to place braces. Just compare your code against the code in the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't closed the main function correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int life = 20;
int poison = 0;
int amount;
char pn;
char lp;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    while(1){
        system("clear");
        printf("Life:%d\nPoison Counters:%d\n\n\n", life, poison);
        printf("\n\n<Life or Poison>(l/p) <positive or negative>(+/-) <amount>(#)\n\n\n>>>");
        scanf("\n\n%c %c %d", &lp, &pn, &amount);
        if(lp == 'l'){
            if(pn == '+'){
                life = life + amount;
            }
            else{
                life = life - amount;
            }
        }else if(lp == 'p'){
            if(pn == '+'){
                poison = poison + amount;
            }
            else{
                poison = poison - amount;
            }
        }else if(lp == 'q'){
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the last three lines and it will compile. That does not mean it is necessarily correct though.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int life = 20;
int poison = 0;
int amount;
char pn;
char lp;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    while(1){
        system("clear");
        printf("Life:%d\nPoison Counters:%d\n\n\n", life, poison);
        printf("\n\n<Life or Poison>(l/p) <positive or negative>(+/-) <amount>(#)\n\n\n>>>");
        scanf("\n\n%c %c %d", &lp, &pn, &amount);
        if(lp == 'l'){
            if(pn == '+'){
                life = life + amount;
            }
            else{
                life = life - amount;
            }
        }else if(lp == 'p'){
            if(pn == '+'){
                poison = poison + amount;
            }
            else{
                poison = poison - amount;
            }
        }else if(lp == 'q'){
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```